# curl checking a checkbox

Tags: php, curl, checkbox

I have a simple php curl function that goes to another site(not owned by me) and fills in the fields and works properly the only thing is i cant get it to check a check box. i cant seem to find an answer.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$searchCriteria = array(
      'historicalMatches' => $_POST['historicalMatches'],  //the checkbox
      'firstName'  => $_POST['firstName'], 
      'middleName' => $_POST['middleName'],
      'lastName'   => $_POST['lastName'], 
      'suffix'     => $_POST['suffix'],
      'age'        => $_POST['age'],
      etc..);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $searchCriteria);
```

i have tried setting the value to 1 and on and checked. The html for the checkbox on the other page is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="historicalMatches" value="on">
```

all i need to do is make sure it is checked everytime. So i can add a 2nd

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'check the box');
```

that just clicks the box I just cant figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where `$_POST['historicalMatches']` is coming from, but that is likely the problem.

Adding:

```
'historicalMatches' => 'on'
```

to your array of `$searchCriteria` should be the proper way to emulate the checkbox being checked.  Simply omitting that value from the postfields would indicate the box was unchecked.

Since the checkbox's value is `on`, just post that value with the checkbox name when you want the checkbox checked, or leave it out of the parameters to have it unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to just fill out the form with cURL, you can try altering the URL string and submit the Posted data that way?

If you don't find the answer try having a look at Http Headers extension for Firefox. From there you can see the URL string that can be used to submit data to the server. Then using cURL and some simple PHP variables you can alter the URL string and execute the request.

It will basically fill out the form for you and submit the data. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but if you don't find how to check the box with your methods, have a look at this!

Comment: i was under the impression if the form method is 'post' then i cant send information through the url.